# how to check hidden input is empty or not use else if conditions in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

this is my hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnship" name="origin_port"  value="">
```

this is my function to get value hidden input field

```
function myfunction(){
     $('#printarray').on('click', function() { 
         var array = []; 
         $("input:checkbox[name=origin_port]:checked").each(function() { 
             array.push($(this).val());  
         }); 
         alert(array);
         $('#hdnship').val(array); 
     }); 
 }
```

Comment: Why you check `checkbox` when your field is marked like a `type="text"`?

Comment: i want to get values to my input filed after i want to run else if condition to check that input field are empty or not ..

Comment: i want to know how to check input field are empty or not use else if conditions

Comment: I got you, but You check the input for `checked` when it is not marked up to be a checkbox `input:checkbox[name=origin_port]:checked`

Answer (score 0):

You can check you input if it is not empty this way:

```
if( !$("input").val() ) {
   console.log("Empty");
}
```

or

```
if( $("input").val().length === 0 ) {
   console.log("Empty");
}
```

or If you're sure it will always operate on a textfield element then you can just use 'this.value':

```
if( !$("input").value ) {
   console.log("Empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking **each input type text** instead of **`checked attribute`** of a checkbox which is basically not the type of your hidden input:

```
function myfunction(){
     $('#printarray').on('click', function() { 
         var array = []; 
         $("input[type=text]").each(function() { 
             if($(this).val().length !== 0) {
                 array.push($(this).val()); 
             } 
         }); 
         alert(array);
         $('#hdnship').val(array); 
     }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also for check `hidden` empty or not

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $(".jsButton").click(function(){
       var array = [],emptyvalue=[]; 
         $("input[type=hidden]").each(function() 
      {        
             if($(this).val().length !== 0)
             {
                 array.push($(this).val());                     
             }
             else
             {
               emptyvalue.push("value");
             } 
         });          
         $('#lblHasValue').html(array.join(',')); 
         $('#lblNotValue').html(emptyvalue.join(',')); 
         
    });   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden"  value="hidden1">
<input type="hidden"  value="hidden2">
<input type="hidden" value="hidden3">
<input type="hidden">
<input type="hidden">

<button type="button" class="jsButton">Set & Get Hidden Value</button> <br/>
<lable id="lblHasValue"></lable> <br/>
<lable id="lblNotValue"></lable>
```

> You can set if `hidden` field has no value if `hidden` field has value
>   you get and set